# Using array keys to call from multidimensional $_POST 'ed arrays?

Tags: php, forms

Thank you for looking at and taking time to answer my question!

I would like to use a multi-dimensional array in a form on my site and then access it using the keys; Like so.

```
<form method="post" action="somescript.php">
    <input type="text" name="name[1][title]">
    <input type="text" name="name[1][descritpion]">
</form>
```

I would then like to access both the index, since that is the ID, and the value of the given _post'ed element. Something like

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST['name']);
 foreach($keys as $id)
 {
      echo "title: " . $_POST['name']['title'][$id];
      echo "description: " . $_POST['name']['description'][$id];
      echo "id: " . $id;
 }
```

Now, the above looks nice and it prints out the correct $id but thats about it. I assume I am putting the "title" or "description" array calls in the wrong place but cannot figure it out. Could someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: i'm not sure on where you want to go with thatm but it seems like there's some missing Quotes on your array keys in `$_POST["description"]["title"][$id]`

Comment: Ah your right, although they are present in my code, just not my example above. Thanks for spotting it tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PHP, you are looking for `$_POST['name']['title'][$id]`, but in your HTML you have `name[1][title]`.

These are not the same array.  You either need to change the HTML to `name[title][1]`, or the PHP to `$_POST['name'][$id]['title']`.

It doesn't matter which you use, just be consistent, though I suggest using `name[title][1]` as that may be easier to work with.

Comment: Superstar, soon as I thought about it I realised you was right.